# AEM MAVEN JAVA 8 - maven-jspc-plugin::maven-jspc-plugin compile jsp result always in error (target 1.5)

Tags: aem

There is a known problem in the maven jspc compiler plugin, which is that it always compiles the jsp in 1.5.
There are the appropriate configurations (jspc.compilerSourceVM and jspc.compilerTargetVM), but setting them generates an error ("Unknown source VM 1.8 ignored.") For which the compilation continues to be performed with 1.5, as it ignores the parameter.
Compiling with target 1.5 does not recognize many syntaxes that were not valid in JAVA 5, causing several errors.
The problem is known and it is possible to find many reports on the WEB, without apparent solutions.
I also tried to use other plugins, but they are all privately developed and not effective anyway.
For now the only working solution is to exclude files from compilation in the project POM, excluding files in the maven-resources-plugin configuration (plugin/executions/execution/configuration/resources/resource/excludes -->  for each jsp under content to exclude from compilation).
Any solutions?

Comment: switch to a newer plugin version?

Comment: I would try a latest release of the jspc plugin. https://sling.apache.org/components/jspc-maven-plugin/jspc-mojo.html Version 2.2.2 defaults to 1.8